# I want to start a site that syndicates other news. Which CMS is most appropriate

Tags: php, content-management-system, syndication

Heres what I am trying to to:

I want to create a site which allows me to syndicate news from all over the web.  I want this to be able to be categorized and possibly tagged.

The process:

I find an article I like, go to my CMS, and add it to my site.  To do this I simply want to add a title of an article, a small description, and possibly and image.  Then, categorize it, add some tags to it.. and submit it.  Now it would appear on my site.

What do you recommend as the CMS of choice?  I am thinking wordpress may do the trick?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, wordpress would be the way to go. You can type the articles and categorize/tag them. You can also install plugins which will read through RSS feeds you add to create links to other sources of new automatically.

The plgun in question is : FeedWordpress

Answer (score 1):

My choice would CMS-Made Simple .